# How To Check The Task Result In the Controller In ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, task, webapi

I have this in my repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CatalogModel>> GetCatalogByName(string _UserId, string _CatalogName)
{
    var data =  await dbcontext.Catalog.Where(x => x.UserId == _UserId).ToListAsync();
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CatalogModel>>(data);
}
```

And currently, this in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCatalogsByName([FromQuery] string UserId, string CatalogName)
{
     var task = repository.Catalog.GetCatalogByName(UserId, CatalogName);
     return Ok(task);
 }
```

So right now I am returning Ok(task) all the time. I would like to check if there is data returned from the repository or not so I can also return NotFound(task). I could not seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: There are a couple of "conceptual problems" here.  1) You need to `await` an async task (see Tuan Tran's [response(https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979099/421195)] below).  Here's a GREAT link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/.  2) [OkResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok) is for returning an `HTTP 200` status code.  That's "transport level". You to return an *APPLICATION LEVEL* value signifying "no data found".  SOLUTION: just return the map (perhaps as a JSON object), not a "task".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wait for the `GetCatalogByName` to complete before examining the result.

A simple `await` will do

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCatalogsByName([FromQuery] string UserId, string CatalogName)
{
     var task = await repository.Catalog.GetCatalogByName(UserId, CatalogName);
     // check task data before return
     return Ok(task);
}
```

But I strongly recommend you to read more about async/await programming [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: I will read through the links you and @paulsm4 provided. Adding `await` would change my controller method to `public async Task<IActionResult> GetCatalogsByName([FromQuery] string UserId, string CatalogName)`.  I still don't have idea how to check the task if there is a record or not.

Comment: Changing a signature to Task<IActionResult> won't change the result of a method.  When you await the Task you actually "unwrap" Task<> and receive the result of it. In your case, after awaiting, the `task` type is IEnumerable<CatalogModel>, so, you can work with `task` as collection using Linq

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs. After reading the article in the suggested links, I gained more knowledge and I now understand how it works.